# How to get a fill below c3.js timeseries chart

Tags: javascript, charts, pubnub, c3.js

How to get a fill below c3.js time series chart like stacked area charts but the values at x-axis remaining time series. I am using EON charting library by PUBNUB but it uses c3.js as base library.

```
eon.chart({
    pubnub   : pubnub,
    history  : false,
    channel  : 'orbit2',
    flow     : true,
    generate : {
        bindto : '#chart',
        size: {
        height: 240,
        width: 380
    },
        data   : {
            x      : 'x',
            labels : true
        },
        axis : {
            x : {
                type : 'timeseries',
                tick : {
                    format : '%H:%M:%S'
                },
                zoom: {
                   enabled: true
                }
            }
        }
    },
    transform : function(m) {
        return { columns : [
            ['x', new Date().getTime()],
            ['Bytes Written', m.Bytes_Written],
            ['Bytes Read', m.Bytes_Read]

        ] };
    }
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## PubNub EON Chart Type

You just need to provide the type of chart to use. There are some samples on the [EON landing page and here is a code sample from one of the examples on that page](https://www.pubnub.com/developers/eon/chart/bar/):

```
eon.chart({
  channel: channel,
  pubnub: pubnub,
  generate: {
    bindto: '#chart',
    data: {
      labels: true,
      type: 'bar'
    },
    bar: {
      width: {
        ratio: 0.5
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
        show: false
    }
  }
});
```

Notice the `data` key that is configured under the `generate` EON parameter. [See c3 docs/examples](http://c3js.org/examples.html) for more details about this.